# CentOS inserting new line of text after another using sed not working

Tags: linux, sed, centos

I'm trying to insert a line of text which is;

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

On the next line after the words;

```
for more information.
```

in my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf using the following command

```
sudo sed '/for more information.'/a include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

But each time i run it, it just returns

```
>
```

Im not very good with this sort of stuff so i was hoping someone could help me out.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the second single-quote.  It is superfluous:

```
sudo sed '/for more information./a include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Also, Because `.` matches *any* character and you probably want it to match only a period, escape it like this:

```
sudo sed '/for more information\./a include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Or this:

```
sudo sed '/for more information[.]/a include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: I used the last command you listed and it just printed out the file, but it didnt actually save the line to the file

Comment: As @DavidCRankin pointed out, add the `-i` option if you want to edit in place.  If you want to save a backup, use `-i.bak` instead and a backup copy will be saved in a file with a `.bak` extension.

Comment: Or, if you want to use an actual file editor instead of a **s**tream **ed**itor, consider using `ed` instead of `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a spurious `'` in your `sed` command. Instead, you need:

```
sudo sed -i '/for more information./a include /etc/nginx/nginx.conf' \
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

(see Johns answer, as the `.` should be escaped if there is a potential for lines with, e.g. `"for more information.stuff"` with information after the closing `.`)

You should also add the `-i` option to edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in place.

Comment: For catching the need for `-i`: +1.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Even this blind ole squirrel finds a nut every now and then `:)`